# Reals as convergent sequence (interpreting "The Foundations of Mathematics" book)

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, decimal-expansion

On page 37 of "The Foundations of Mathematics" (2nd edition) the authors write of the reals...

> We can make the completeness property of the reals very plausible in terms of our ideas about decimals. Let $(a_n)$ be an increasing sequence of real numbers, with $a_n \leq k$ for all $k$.

(My first question: doesn't this condition mean $a_n$ is less than any number? I am already confused, but maybe it should say "all $n$"?)

Continuing...

> The set of integers between $a_n - 1$ and $k$ is finite, so there is an integer $b_0$ that is the largest integer for which some term $a_{n_0}$ of the sequence is $\geq b_0$. Now all terms $a_n$ are less than $b_0 + 1$.

I'm afraid I really don't follow this at all, surely there are (potentially) a very large number of such integers? I suspect I have not grasped what the authors are trying to say at all. Could someone explain, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $n$ instead of $k$.

If for some $m$, $a_m \ge b_0+1$, then $b_0+1$ is less than or equal to the largest integer $s$ such that for some term (here $m$) of the sequence, $a_m \ge s$. But this integer $s$ is $b_0$ by assumption. Contradiction

Comment: Yes, that is clearly a typo.  It should be "for all n" not for all k.  That is, the set of terms has upper bound k.

Comment: @user247327 yes, that's clear. Why did you feel the urge to restate this?